# How does one read a .dif file with Python

Tags: python, spreadsheet

I am working on a project that requires me to read a file with a .dif extension. Dif stands for data information exchange. The file opens nicely in Open Office Calc. Then you can easily save as a csv file, however when I open in Python all I get are random characters that don't make sense. Here is the last code that I tried just to see if I could read.

```
txt = open('C:\myfile.dif', 'rb').read()
print txt
```

I would even be open to programatically converting the file to csv first.  before opening if someone knows how to do that. As always, any help is much appreciated. Below is a partial screenshot of what I get when I run the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hadn't heard of this file format. Went and got a sample [here](http://file.fyicenter.com/72_Spreadsheet_.DIF_File_Extension_for_Data_Interchange_Format.html).

I tested your method and it works fine:

```
>>> content = open(r"E:\sample.dif", 'rb').read()
>>> print (content)
b'TABLE\r\n0,1\r\n"EXCEL"\r\nVECTORS\r\n0,8\r\n""\r\nTUPLES\r\n0,3\r\n""\r\nDATA\r\n0,0\r\n""\r\n-1,0\r\nBOT\r\n1,0\r\n"Welcome to File Extension FYI Center!"\r\n1,0\r\n""\r\n1,0\r\n""\r\n-1,0\r\nBOT\r\n1,0\r\n""\r\n1,0\r\n""\r\n1,0\r\n""\r\n-1,0\r\nBOT\r\n1,0\r\n"ID"\r\n1,0\r\n"Type"\r\n1,0\r\n"Description"\r\n-1,0\r\nBOT\r\n0,1\r\nV\r\n1,0\r\n"ASP"\r\n1,0\r\n"Active Server Pages"\r\n-1,0\r\nBOT\r\n0,2\r\nV\r\n1,0\r\n"JSP"\r\n1,0\r\n"JavaServer Pages"\r\n-1,0\r\nBOT\r\n0,3\r\nV\r\n1,0\r\n"PNG"\r\n1,0\r\n"Portable Network Graphics"\r\n-1,0\r\nBOT\r\n0,4\r\nV\r\n1,0\r\n"GIF"\r\n1,0\r\n"Graphics Interchange Format"\r\n-1,0\r\nBOT\r\n0,5\r\nV\r\n1,0\r\n"WMV"\r\n1,0\r\n"Windows Media Video"\r\n-1,0\r\nEOD\r\n'
>>>
```

The question is what is in the file and how do you want to handle it. Personally I liked:

```
with open(r"E:\sample.dif", 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print (line)
```

In the first code block, that long line that has a `b''` (for bytes!) in front of it can be iterated on `\r\n`:

```
b'TABLE\r\n'
b'0,1\r\n'
b'"EXCEL"\r\n'
b'VECTORS\r\n'
b'0,8\r\n'
b'""\r\n'
b'TUPLES\r\n'
b'0,3\r\n'
b'""\r\n'
b'DATA\r\n'
b'0,0\r\n'
.
.
.
b'"Windows Media Video"\r\n'
b'-1,0\r\n'
b'EOD\r\n'
```

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I get after running the code with my file. I wonder if it's some kind of encoding problem?

Comment: @MikeC. what environment are you using? Mine was straight with the native IDLE; also, try downloading the sample I linked in the answer; test your method against that.

Comment: Good idea. I'll give it a try in the morning.

Comment: Problem solved. Client opened the file in Excel of he could save as tab delimited. He then renamed xls file as dif. and sent to me as original file. Sheese!